# Moving Bitcoin-QT's location

Tags: storage-footprint

I have bitcoin-qt installed on my Ubuntu box which has an SSD as the main OS drive.

I understand that bitcoin-qt is a full client/node and uses a lot of disk activity, which is why I want it off my expensive SSD and want it on my cheaper HDD.  How do I move the client so all the node checking work it does which is disk intensive is done on the secondary HDD instead of the primary SSD?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

---

**UPDATE:**

I just edited the file:

`/usr/share/applications$ sudo gedit bitcoin-qt.desktop`

and changed:

`Exec=/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt %u`

to

`Exec=/usr/bin/bitcoin-qt -datadir=/new_location/.bitcoin %u`

I have just tried loading bitcoin-qt and it currently says `Rescanning`.

Have I made the changes correctly?  It's been scanning for 5 minutes now...

Comment: That looks correct.  Bitcoin-Qt will verify blocks when it starts and this can take several minutes.  The rescan message says it is looking for missing transactions, which I don't think it normally does unless you import a new private key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the -datadir option to specify a new location for the bitcoin data directory.  Copy the existing bitcoin data directory to the new location and then restart bitcoin-qt.  Check [**here**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) for information on locating the default data directory.

Comment: Please see update to original question.

Comment: Took about 12 hours to complete and I had to reinstall bitcoin-qt in the end to get it all to work again...